# Is there a command to get the number of lines of code added, deleted, modified for a git commit?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I'm using below command

`git log --pretty=format:"%h,%cn,%cs"` which gives me the commit ID, committer name, and commit date. But what I need is the number of lines added/modified/deleted for every commit ID.

FYI: I'm not looking for difference between the commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `--stat` to your command. For example...

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h,%cn,%cs" --stat

e5a3f23256,Yuta Saito,2022-08-04
 ext/extmk.rb | 2 +-
 lib/mkmf.rb  | 6 +++++-
 tool/fake.rb | 1 +
 3 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

c69582a540,Yuta Saito,2022-08-04
 configure.ac | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be after [`--shortstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---shortstat), which will tell you how many files changed, how many lines were added ("inserted") and how many lines were deleted.

You can use it with `git show` and `git log`.